# Print a pdf displayed in <object> tag angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have created a popup in Angular2 which will show PDF file from server like a report viewer, This PDF is embeded in  tag like below

```
<object width="870" height="650" type="application/pdf" data="http://localhost/amar/test.pdf?#zoom=85&scrollbar=0&toolbar=0&navpanes=0" id="doc">
 </object>
```

i tried to open it in a new window and then print like mentioned in several examples, but it wasnt working

```
    var URL = "http://localhost/amar/test.pdf";
    var printWindow = window.open(URL);
    printWindow.print() 
   //Not working
```

i tried with postMessage() it was also not working

```
 var PrintThis = function (val) {
       printWindow.focus();
       printWindow.print();

    }

    printWindow.addEventListener("message", PrintThis);
    printWindow.postMessage("Print", "*");
    //in this case iam able to get the data in printhis()
    //but its also not working
```

Please help or provide me with ideas about how can i print a PDF in angular2 Or Javascript

Comment: So which part is the issue? Opening in a new window? Printing? Or both?

Comment: i am able to open but not able to print